# How do I get the value of this function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that converts an image URL to a base64 image string. The thing is that the function needs a callback, and I use a console.log to print the string (which works), but I need the string to be saved in a variable. Here is the code:

```
function convertImageToBase64(imgUrl, callback) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    image.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        callback && callback(dataUrl);
    }
    image.src = imgUrl;
}
```

And here's how I call the function:

```
convertImageToBase64(imgEmpresa, console.log);
convertImageToBase64(imgPropia, console.log);
```

Both img variables are URL strings I obtain through other methods.
It works perfectly fine, and the output of the console.log is the base64 string. But the thing is that I need that variable to be stored somewhere and I have literally no clue on how to do it.

I tried making a function to serve as callback that just returns the variable, but that doesn't work

Comment: Are you allowed to change the original function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "promisify" it:

```
async function convertImageToBase64(imgUrl, callback) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        const image = new Image();
        image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        image.src = imgUrl;

        image.onload = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
            canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            resolve(dataUrl)
        }
    })
}
```

and then `await convertImageToBase64(...)` somewhere else.

See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much. Btw, is there any repercussion for making all my functions async ? Since I needed to do it on my window.onload because of the "await" part

Comment: @Malice there's no good reason to make an ordinary function involving no asynchronous operations `async`. However it's a wonderful idea when you *are* dealing with asynchronous APIs, because it really cleans up code.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways. 1) You return the value from the function and store the value outside. Or you do it already in the function.

```js
function convertImageToBase64(imgUrl, callback) {
  return var;
}
localStorage.setItem('test', convertImageToBase64(imgUrl, callback));
```

**or**

```js
function convertImageToBase64(imgUrl, callback) {
  // storeInLocalStorage
  localStorage.setItem('test', var);
}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no return in your function. You need to [return that value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
function convertImageToBase64(imgUrl, callback) {
   // some magic ...
   return imgSrc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can not change the original function: Use a closure to store the value, or pass the function that needs to consume it later on.

```
var stored = "";
convertImageToBase64(imgEmpresa,  (d) => { stored = d; });
console.log(stored);
```